# Don´t reciving notification in Orion ,atribute reference in Orion instance /ngsi10/subscribeContext not send information to my server

Tags: fiware-orion

I need something help about Orion instance /ngsi10/subscribeContext.

I made a ngsi10/updateContext and I recived this response

```
{
  "contextResponses" : [
    {
      "contextElement" : {
        "type" : "Room",
        "isPattern" : "false",
        "id" : "Room1",
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "temperature",
            "type" : "float",
            "value" : ""
          },
          {
            "name" : "pressure",
            "type" : "integer",
            "value" : ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode" : {
        "code" : "200",
        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

in atribute "reference" in subscribeContext  send : "http://195.81.125.89/webservices/scriptupdatefile.php"
this script only save the information in txt.
  I sent /ngsi10/subscribeContext

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Room",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": " Room1"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "temperature"
    ],
    "reference": "http://195.81.125.89/webservices/scriptupdatefile.php",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONTIMEINTERVAL",
            "condValues": [
                "PT10S"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I probed too with

```
"type": ""type": "ONCHANGE"
condValues": ["temperature"]
```

and  I recibed the correct subscription...(ngsi10/unsubscribeContext work fine...)

```
{
  "subscribeResponse" : {
    "subscriptionId" : "556f23bd1407221d5bc569ce",
    "duration" : "P1M"
  }
}
```

I saw in my virtual box CENTOS that my subcription is correct, and update every x time.... , but in my logs server(http://195.81.125.89...) and my txt did not see any operation or any call....`enter code here`

thanks!!

Comment: Could you edit your question in order to include the subscribeContext request (in the same way you are including the updateContext), please? Thanks!

Comment: Hi fgalan, I add subscribeContext. Thanks!

Comment: Could you also add the content of scriptupdatefile.php (use gist if it too large to include it in the question post: https://gist.github.com/), please? In addition, what the "enter code here" sentence means in your question post?

Comment: What do you mean by "I saw in my virtual box CENTOS that my subcription is correct, and update every x time", please?

Comment: Hi, first thanks for respond my questions.
The first question:
this script only is a test... only write data in a file,                                      $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$file=fopen("datos.txt","a");
fwrite($file,$data);
fclose($file); the php code is correct I probed this  with other app.

Comment: The second question:
I mean, I see in the log of server every x time info of the subscription... and for example when I sent ngsi10/unsubscribeContext the information ceased to paint , for this reason  I said  "my subcription is correct", because I saw every x time log paint information, but in my external server  I don´t see conexion , don´t see subscribeContext send information to my server

Comment: In order to see if the notification is received at the web server VM, please try the following: 1) shutdown the web/php server (so the 80 port gets free), 2) run a nc process listening on that port with `nc -l 80` (you would need root permissions to do that). Next, check if nc is receiving any input.

Comment: Hi, don´t see conexion when I send http request... nc is not receiving any input. 
But when I make a test with telnet(195.81.125.89 80) is correct . I don´t know what happen.

Comment: I can send since centOS to my server the same request http and I can see in my server this call , but for the callback of subscribeContext don't see anything

Comment: Not sure of understanding... Do the following: 1) shutdown any process running on port 80, 2) run `nc -l 80` in one terminal, 3) run `curl localhost:80` in another terminal. Are you seeing any input in the nc terminal? Once I know the answer to this question, I can guide you to the next step.

Comment: This is the result that obtain with your steps :                                                                                    GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Host: localhost
Accept: */*

Comment: Hi, I try to connect context with cygnus("reference": "http://127.0.0.1:5050/notify") but don´t work too, Nothing comes to cygnus, I think I need something in Orion Context Broker, because  when information arrive to Context...this information don´t go to my server or to cygnus

Comment: Please, do next the following test: 1) shutdown any process running on port 80, 2) run `nc -l 80` in one terminal, 3) run `curl http://195.81.125.89` in *the machine where Orion is running*. Are you seeing any input in the nc terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by "reference": "http://195.81.125.89/webservices/scriptupdatefile.php"  ... As *reference* you need to put the information of a server (IP:PORT/PATH) that will accept a connection and read what the broker sends to it via socket. It seems like you want a PHP script to be launched for every notification ... This is not how it works (I might have misunderstood the whole thing, but the php suffix of your reference makes me wonder ...). In short, you need a running process that accepts incoming connections on IP:PORT.

Comment: Hi, first thanks for respond my questions.
Yes ,the Script want be launched for every notification.
This script is in a  external server(for example one.com ) , is a webservice, only receive information by post and save this information in a file.
I mean, I use in other app( not fiware) this type webservices...send informatión every x time ... My webservice obtain this information $POST[].... and save in bbdd or something. My php code only read information send by (post/get)

Comment: The thing is, you need a running process to receive the notifications. A process that accepts csocke connections on the IP and PORT of the *reference* of the subscription. This running process can of course spawn a PHP script if it so desires. But you need this process I'm talking about. Without that, the notification will fail as there is nobody listening to it.